# Property not found on object of type Error?

Tags: object, properties

```
DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
dvController.selectedCollege = selectedCollege;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
[dvController release];
dvController = nil;
```

I'm getting the error

> Property 'selectedCollege' not found on object of type 'DetailViewController' in line 3.